# How can I convert base64 string to image and upload the file in storage and save the path in the database

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2, laravel-5.8

I am building an SPA. I am getting base64 string from my vue component in my laravel controller. How can I convert base64 string to a file. Then upload the site into my laravel local storage and then save the path in the database table ?

I have googled almost every link and tried too many things. I even tried image intervention but the only thing I was able to achieve was to upload the file into the laravel storage but wasn't able to store the right path in the database table.

Here is my controller code

```
$team = new Team;
        $team->hood_id = $user->hood->id;
        $team->title = $request->title;
        $team->max_no_of_players = $request->max_no_of_players;
        $team->description = $request->description;
        $team->about_us = $request->about_us;
        $team->email = $request->email;
        $team->contact_no = $request->contact_no;
        $team->meetup_place = $request->meetup_place;
        /**
         * Image base64 converting code starts from here
         */
        $image = $request->image;
         preg_match("/data:image\/(.*?);/",$image,$image_extension); // extract the image extension
         $image = preg_replace('/data:image\/(.*?);base64,/','',$image); // remove the type part
         $image = str_replace(' ', '+', $image);
         $imageName = 'image_' . time() . '.' . $image_extension[1]; //generating unique file name;
         $team->image = Storage::disk('public')->put($imageName, base64_decode($image));
```

I should be able to use Storage::url($image); when fetching the teams from database table. But right now I am not getting the correct path, Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

In this way, you can fetch the file from the Base64 URL, I used this way.

```
    $pos = strpos($fileBase64Url, ';');
    $filetype = explode('/', substr($fileBase64Url, 0, $pos))[1]; //get file type

    $contents = file_get_contents($fileBase64Url); //get the content from the URL

    $unique_name = 'filename.' . $filetype; //file name 

    Storage::put('/public/folderName/' . $unique_name, $contents); //save to the directory 

    //$unique_name (Save this name to the Database)
```

And this is the path of this image file

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/folderName/filename.jpg (remove public form url)
```

Comment: This seems to be working fine. But I want to store that url in the table as well !! How do I do that ?

Comment: Store the only name of the file. like $team->image = $filename; and save it to the database. if you want to show this file in the Vue or blade part then use this URL in the img tag (127.0.0.1:8000/storage/folderName/{{$team->image}}) and please check the syntex for the VueJs